# addToSet in mongodb for array of array?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I am having an array of array within a collection and i need to know to use addToSet to add an item in that array.. Following is my document structure

```
db.Timeline.insert({
Email : "sk.sagarkhan95@gmail.com",
BlogPosts :[{
Title : "Party Time",
Name : "Sagar Khan",
Description : "Some Description",
Date : new Date(),
Image : "users/sk.sagarkhan95@gmail.com/pictures/prof-pic.jpg",
Likes : ["hs@gmail.com"],
    Comments : [ {               **<-- Need to addToSet in this array**
    email : "hs@gmail.com",
    Name : "Harish Shinde",
    Image : "users/hs@gmail.com/pictures/prof-pic.jpg",
    comment : "Wow its soo true",
    Time : new Date()
     }]
}]
});
```

As you can see there are two arrays inside Timeline collection 
i.e

> BlogPosts->Comments

i need to add an item to **comments** array that means i need to get down 2 levels... I have no idea on how to do this

i Have tried something like this looking at the previous solutions but no luck

```
db.Timeline.update({Email :" sk.sagarkhan95@gmail.com"},{$addToSet:{ "BlogPosts.Comments":{"Title":"null"}}});
```

and this

```
db.Timeline.update({Email :" sk.sagarkhan95@gmail.com"},{$addToSet:{ 'BlogPosts.$.Comments':{"Title":"test"}}});
```

And yes i need to do this in php but first i am trying it by console...
So if i get PHP syntax as well then it will make my work easier...
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try thinking which of blog posts needs to be updated. The positional `$` is good way, you need to add something to query part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work, you must specify which element in `BlogPosts` needs to be updated on top of the `email` since you're trying to add an array into an array. You'll have to tell Mongo which array you are trying to add your array to. Use the positional operator `$` when updating

`db.Timeline.updateOne(
   {"Email": "sk.sagarkhan95@gmail.com", "BlogPosts.Title" : "PartyTime"},
   {$addToSet : {"BlogPosts.$.Comments" : {"Title" : "test"}}}
)`